# The title of a movie about a cliff where things rise up, and somebody commits suicide there

Tags: identify-this-movie

Main characters: A black taxi driver, An old white man.

Language: English

Genre: Drama

Date of release: Most likely post 2000. No earlier than mid 90s

Country: I assume USA, but possibly UK, NZ, AU

The old white man gets into the black taxi driver's cab. He pays him dearly.
He has a history. A life of regret. Although the taxi driver feels something is wrong, he cannot quite fully grasp the old man's situation. He tries to intervene with little success.

The film depicts the old man watching a family which can be deduced to be somehow related to the old man. Just as the old man resists attempts by the taxi driver to get closer, the family does not welcome the old man.

There is a cliff nearby (which is depicted in the poster for the movie), where things are known to rise up (presumably by the wind) after falling down.

The old man asks the taxi driver to be taken there. The taxi driver drives him there and accompanies him up the cliff. Although the taxi driver does not want the old man to die, he respects his wishes and descends. Finding another ridge on the way down, he throws a twig and sees it rise.

I always remembered the title of the movie to be "Goodbye echo". But not only is there no such movie, variations of the mistaken title yields no results (Goodbye/Farewell/Byebye Echo/eco, etc)

Can anybody identify this movie for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heartbreaking [Goodbye Solo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1095442/combined) from 2008.

> On the lonely roads of Winston-Salem, North Carolina, two men forge an improbable friendship that will change both of their lives forever. Solo is a Senegalese cab driver working to provide a better life for his young family. William is a tough Southern good ol' boy with a lifetime of regrets. One man's American dream is just beginning, while the other's is quickly winding down. But despite their differences, both men soon realize they need each other more than either is willing to admit.

The plot unfolds as you described: William hires Solo to drive him to the cliff where he's planning to take his own life. Everything else happens there too. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Thank you very much. It was "Goodbye solo" not "goodbye echo" as I mistakenly recalled. Is upvoting the only way to express my thanks?

Comment: Resolution, done!